# Reset Iterator position to 0 in a nested while-loop

Tags: java, loops, iterator

I am performing iteration on two lists.

```
// events and items are two lists.

Iterator<Event> eventIterator = events.iterator();
Iterator<EventItem> itemIterator = items.iterator();

while (eventIterator.hasNext()) {

    Event event = eventIterator.next();

    while (itemIterator.hasNext()) {

        EventItem item = itemIterator.next();

        if (event.getId().equals(item.getEventId())) {

            // CLAIMED
            itemIterator.remove();
        }
    }

    // PROBLEM IS HERE.

}
```

**Problem:**

I looped through `itemIterator` to the end, and also removed the items from `itemIterator` if an item gets claimed. But, when next iteration on `eventIterator` will run, `itemIterator` is already at its end.

How can I reset `itemIterator` to position `0` without reinitiating it using `items.iterator()` because that will bring back items removed from `itemIterator` for next iteration.

One `item` from `itemIterator` can only be claimed by one `event` from `eventIterator`. So, it doesn't make sense for me to keep that item in iteration after it is claimed. Hence, I remove the item from `itemIterator`.

I am open to alternatives if they decrease the number of iterations than the traditional for-each loop.

Comment: It doesnt bring back items. The underlying collection is modified

Comment: So you're trying to remove every `EventItem` whose `id` is in `Event`?

Comment: *that will bring back items removed from itemIterator* - **nah**

Comment: I didn't know, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I reset `itemIterator` to position 0 without reinitiating it using `items.iterator()` because that will bring back items removed from `itemIterator` for next iteration.

No, it won't. `itemIterator.remove()` removes the item from the **collection** you got the iterator from, not just the iterator. If you get a new iterator from that collection, it won't have that item on it anymore; you removed it. From [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--):

> **Removes from the underlying collection** the last element returned by this iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only once per call to `next()`.

*(my emphasis)*

You can't reset an iterator; just get a new one, within the `while`.

```
Iterator<Event> eventIterator = events.iterator();

while (eventIterator.hasNext()) {
    Event event = eventIterator.next();

    Iterator<EventItem> itemIterator = items.iterator();
    while (itemIterator.hasNext()) {
        EventItem item = itemIterator.next();
        if (event.getId().equals(item.getEventId())) {
            // CLAIMED
            itemIterator.remove();
        }
    }

    // If you need to loop a second time for some reason:
    itemIterator = items.iterator();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using nested loops like this is O(N * M) and is expensive, but it's also verbose which obscures the purpose of what you are trying to achieve.  I suggest you use streams from Java 8.

```
// get all the event's ids
Set<String> eventIds = events.stream()
        .map(Event::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

// remove the entries from items with a matching id.
items.removeIf(i -> eventIds.contains(i.getEventId()));
```

This has a time complexity of O(N + M).

> And, removed/claimed items get added to another list (I call it EventDto, data transfer object)

You can do that by building the list first.

```
// remove the entries from items with a matching id.
List<EventItem> toMove = items.stream()
                              .filter(i -> eventIds.contains(i.getEventId()))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
items.removeAll(toMove);
anotherList.addAll(toMove);
```

---

This might be more efficient if the id was used as the key of a map

e.g.

```
Map<String, Event> events = ... // events keyed by id
Map<String, EventItem> items = ... // event items keys by eventId

events.keySet().removeAll(items.keySet());
```

Comment: I agree with you. However, I tried to make my code minimal for this question, hence removing my needs. I have a list of Events and Items. And, removed/claimed items get added to another list (I call it EventDto, data transfer object). Changing my question now will invalidate the accepted answer. But, thanks for your approach, I am going to use it.

Comment: @rupinderjeet I added an example of how to move the entries.